# 32 bit DLL within WOW64

Tags: vb.net, dll

I've read about running 32 bit DLLs in 64 bit environments, especially [here](http://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/). But I'm still getting errors. Here's what I have. I have a real old 32-bit DLL that can't be converted to 64 bit. I have another DLL, my own, written in VB.NET, that I've compiled as x86. It calls the older one. My DLL is part of a Windows Service which I've compiled to x86 as well. So all x86 running on a 64-bit Win2012 server. The older DLL is actually installed on the machine itself, not part of my DLL or the Win Svc because of the nature of that DLL.

The older DLL is invoked using the standard X = CreateObject("oldDLL"). Everything works until I try to call a method on X. Then the method can't be found.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This sounds more like a COM interop issue rather than a x64 vs x86 issue.  What happens if you add a reference to the old COM DLL to your project (which will automatically create RCW classes) and then don't use `CreateObject` but instead use the constructors for the COM classes?

Comment: Please include source code covering the definition in the original DLL and the P/Invoke definition in your VB code.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem to use CreateObject. Is the older DLL a COM component? If so, make sure it is registered using `regsvr32` in an elevated command prompt. If you have VB6 anywhere, open it and try to reference the old DLL in Project->References.

Comment: The old DLL is written in java and compiled with the 2000 era MS JVM. I guess that's a COM object. Honestly I inherited this so I can't say I'm COM-savvy.  As for code, it's standard VB.NET object = CreateObject("mything"). Nothing more than that.  I will definitely try including in the project.

Comment: You'll need to get a 64-bit version of this component to get ahead.  Only other alternative you have is to keep it in a separate 32-bit helper process.  That's technically possible by using a COM surrogate, it requires knowing enough about it to write the registry entries correctly.  Or use a .NET process that you talk to with, say, WCF.

Comment: Based on the article I linked to, my 32-bit DLLs should just run  because of WOW64.  CRAIG - I did find out that it is a COM object. It was registered with regsvr32, but what do you mean by 'elevated command prompt'?  Any other suggestions why it just doesn't run with wow64? Or does wow64 just make it possible to run at all but you still need some work, like the RCW type thing that was suggested or COM+.

Comment: Well, everything is now 32-bit, I've included the old dll in my project and referenced it so I can now see the native methods, and code that way, so oldObj.doSomething(X,Y).  NOW at runtime when it gets to the doSomething call I get the Object reference not set to an instance of an object error even though I specifically have a check right before the call to see if oldObj is nothing, and that comes back false (oldObj is not nothing).  Any ideas short of having to explore COM+ or PInvoke?